# Which of the phrases sounds natural?

Tags: grammar, questions, auxiliary-verbs

Could you please tell me whether the question is grammatical?

> Which of the phrases sound natural?

Don't we need to use auxiliary verb do/does here to form a question?

Comment: Please [don't use comments just to say thank you](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4744/9161). The best way to say "thank you" on Stack Exchange is to up-vote content you found helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subject and verb disagree here.  The verb needs to agree with the singular "which", not the plural "phrases".  Therefore:

> Which of the phrases sounds natural?

We can consider these similar sentences to help us understand:

> Which phrase sounds natural?
>
> Which phrase among the ones here sounds natural?

and not: "Which phrase sound natural?"

> Don't we need to use auxiliary verb do/does here to form a question?

It's not necessary, and I don't think there is a rephrasal which means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in itself, the sentence you cited would be ungrammatical for it would be counted as a subordinate clause. I think the right version would be:

> **Which of the phrases does sound natural?**

Let's say your friend asked you that and you are describing what he asked to any other person, then would you be using what you cited. For instance:

> My friend asks me **which of the phrases sounds natural**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still a little bit unsure about the correctness of the question "Which of the phrases does sound natural?" It looks a little unusual to me...

Comment: For more clarification, I really want you to have a look at this thread of a related answer - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286172/how-to-explain-the-lack-of-auxiliary-verb-in-some-questions